# ¿Cómo renombrar la columna nueva creada por .size()?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataset

Necesito saber como renombrar la columna que se crea después de aplicar `.size()`

```
#Productos mas vendidos
rep = Train.groupby(['product_id']).size()
rep = rep.sort_values(ascending = False)  
print(rep.head(10)
```

Tengo esto y el resultado que me da analizando los datos es este:

```
    product_id
24852    18726
13176    15480
21137    10894
21903     9784
47626     8135
47766     7409
47209     7293
16797     6494
26209     6033
27966     5546
dtype: int64
```

Esa columna que sale a la derecha es la que quiero renombrar y no se como debería hacerlo, he leído en foros pero no me queda claro

PD: también quisiera saber como correr ese `product_id` para que se vea mas ordenado:(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pandas.DataFrame.GroupBy.size` retorna una Serie en tu caso, con `product_id` como índice, no un DataFrame. Si lo que quieres es crear una columna con los valores de la Serie y darle un nombre puedes simplemente usar [`pandas.Series.to_frame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_frame.html):

```
import pandas as pd

Train = pd.DataFrame({"product_id": (24852, 13176, 21137, 21903, 47626,
                                     13176, 13176, 21903, 21903, 47626,
                                     24852, 21903, 21137, 21903, 47626,
                                     13176, 13176, 47626, 21903, 47626)})

rep = Train.groupby(['product_id']).size()
rep.sort_values(ascending=False, inplace=True)
rep = rep.to_frame("Size")
```

> ```
> >>> rep
>             Size
> product_id      
> 21903          6
> 47626          5
> 13176          5
> 24852          2
> 21137          2
> ```